# retrieving array from angular.factory in my controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

This is the first time i am implementing a factory and it looks like its something very minor but i just cant seem to pinpoint what it could be.

my factory code is:

```
angular.module('dashboardApp').factory('randomNumberService', function($http) {
var num, min, max, col, base, format, md, myData;
var numbersArray = [];
var newArrayTwo = [
    [],
    []
];
var getRandom = {
    myNumbers: []
};
getRandom.numbers = function() {

    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://www.random.org/integers/',
        params: { num: 14, min: 9, max: 80, col: 1, base: 10, format: 'plain', md: 'new' }
    }).success(function(response, data, status, config) {
        numbersArray = response.split(response.charAt(2));
        console.log(numbersArray[0]);
        angular.copy(numbersArray, getRandom.myNumbers);
    }).error(function(data, status) {
        //error code here
    });
}
return getRandom;
```

});

and im calling it from my controller:

```
    randomNumberService.numbers();
var myData = randomNumberService.myNumbers;
```

Basically when i console.log the array (myData) it shows me brackets which i have to expand to view the array. Theres a little i when i hover on it it says "object value at left was snapshotted when logged" and when i try to console.log myData[0] it says undefined. How can it be undefined when it showed me the entire array without the index?

Answer (score 0):

Looks you are doing good.

If you want to see the result on the page, first put the value on scope

```
$scope.myData = randomNumberService.myNumbers;
```

In html:

```
<pre>{{myData | json}}</pre>
```

See what it is showing on the page

Answer (score 0):

You can do better in your factory:
For example using $q:

```
angular.module('dashboardApp')
  .factory('randomNumberService', function($http, $q) {
    var num, min, max, col, base, format, md, myData;
    var numbersArray = [];
    var newArrayTwo = [[],[]];

    return { 
      getNumbers: function(){
            var defer = $q.defer();
            $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: 'https://www.random.org/integers/',
                    params: { num: 14, min: 9, max: 80, col: 1, base: 10, format: 'plain', md: 'new' }
                 })
             .success(function(response, data, status, config) {
                    numbersArray = response.split(response.charAt(2));
                    defer.resolve(numbersArray);
                }).error(function(data, status) {
                    defer.reject();
                });

             return defer.promise;
      }
    }
```

And in your controller:

```
randomNumberService.getNumbers()
 .then( function(data){
   $scope.myData = data;
 });
```